# How to change Spotify Facebook login to email login

Tags: login, spotify

Is there a way to change my Spotify login from using Facebook to using just email and password?

Comment: I had to [contact](https://www.spotify.com/us/about-us/contact/) Spotify customer support to unlink it from Facebook.

Answer (score 2):

You can do so by disconnecting from Facebook. The following instruction shows how to do this:

> **Disconnect from Facebook.**
>
> Since you have a dedicated Spotify account, disconnecting from
>   Facebook is easy.
>
> In the desktop client:
>
> Windows - Go to Edit > Preferences > Social Network > Disconnect from
>   Facebook.
>
> Mac - Go to Spotify > Preferences > Social Network > Disconnect from
>   Facebook.  Once you have done that, your Spotify account is no longer
>   linked to Facebook, you need not continue any of the steps below.
>
> You may find due to data caching in the client, that you still see
>   Facebook information (such as the People list) hanging around, a quick
>   clean reinstallation of the application should fix that for you.
>
> If you can't see the option to connect/disconnect, then you are logged
>   into a Spotify account created with Facebook not a dedicated Spotify
>   one.
>
> https://community.spotify.com/t5/Accounts-and-Subscriptions/Tutorial-How-to-Disconnect-Spotify-from-Facebook/td-p/247266

Comment: This answer only works to disconnect Facebook if you signed up to spotify with your email address and then linked it to your Facebook as a secondary step. The question is actually about 'logging in' to Spotify using Facebook, which means you signed up with Facebook credentials.

Answer (score 1):

If you signed up to Spotify with Facebook credentials and use your Facebook ID/password to log in to Spotify, then there is no simple way to convert the account.

You need to [contact Spotify support](https://support.spotify.com/us/contact-spotify-support/).

Only people who signed up to Spotify with their email account and then added Facebook connection as a secondary step can disconnect it in settings.